# Elixir syntax - defining multiple functions with similar signatures and no end keyword

Tags: elixir

I am checking out a sample application from: https://github.com/shamshirz/scoreboard/blob/master/lib/scoreboard/games/games.ex

I have come across the following code, which I have marked up based on my understanding.

```
def query(Score, params) do #defined function query/2
    params
    |> Map.put_new(:limit, 10) #adding to the "dictionary"
    |> Map.put_new(:order, :total) #""
    |> Map.to_list() #flattening out the map
    |> Enum.reduce(Score, &apply_param/2) #call apply_param/2 for each item
  end

#defines query/2... now we have two query/2... Wait, how is this?
#I guess this one is query/2 with a private argument (_params). 
#Also, this doesnt have an `end`
  def query(queryable, _params), do: queryable 

#defines apply_param/2 with no end
  def apply_param({:limit, num}, queryable), do: queryable |> limit(^num) 

#defines another apply_param/2, no end again!
  def apply_param({:order, field}, queryable), do: queryable |> order_by(desc: ^field)

#defines another apply_param/2, no end again!...
  def apply_param({:player_id, player_id}, queryable),
    do: queryable |> where(player_id: ^player_id)

#again...
  def apply_param(_param, queryable), do: queryable

#finally a function I can read (I think)
#take in a query and execute, if its null -> error, result -> return with :ok
  def get(queryable, id) do
    case Repo.get(queryable, id) do
      nil ->
        {:error, :not_found}

      result ->
        {:ok, result}
    end
  end
  #look at those nice "end"-ings
```

What are those `apply_param` definitions? Why don't they have an `end` and how can they all have seemingly similar signatures? I.E. they take in a `tuple` and a second `queryable` variable?

Comment: `do ... end` is just syntactic sugar to a keyword list `do:` item. The same thing goes with else. You can see an example of this in the definition of [`if/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2900).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `end` keyword if you are using a one line function.  To make a one line function you use `do` with a preceding command and trailing colon.  The following functions are the same:

```rb
# Single line
def say_hello(name), do: IO.puts("Hello #{name}")

# Multiline
def say_hello(name) do
  IO.puts("Hello #{name}")
end
```

For your other question, all of definitions of `apply_param/2` are an example of pattern matching.  Each function is matching on a different parameter, which are being applied in the `reduce` statement in the first function.

The list of params might look like this:

```rb
[{:limit, 5}, {:order, :asc}]
```

So the reduce call would be called with something like this:

```rb
Enum.reduce([{:limit, 5}, {:order, :asc}], score,  &apply_param/2)
```

Each param would be applied to the score, returning a modified score for the next iteration of the reduce function.

The `{:limit, 5}` parameter would match the first function, while the `{:order, :asc}` wouldn't match the first function, but would match the second function.

```rb
def apply_param({:limit, num}, queryable), do: queryable |> limit(^num) 

def apply_param({:order, field}, queryable), do: queryable |> order_by(desc: ^field)

def apply_param({:player_id, player_id}, queryable),
    do: queryable |> where(player_id: ^player_id)

def apply_param(_param, queryable), do: queryable
```

In the final function, the leading underscore in `_param` means that it will match anything.  This is generally a good idea: having a default case for unknown input.

---

Here is an example of something I do frequently that shows off both of these things:

```rb
# This function declaration without a body is called a header, it is used so # I don't have define the default value of 5 in multiple places
def fetch_data(id, retries_left \\ 5)

# In this case, where the retries_left matches on the value of 0, I want to
# raise an error.  Since this is small, I use a one-line function
def fetch_data(id, 0), do: raise "Retries exhausted, could not fetch data!"

# In any other case, try getting the data again
def fetch_data(id, retries_left) do
  case do_request(id)
    # It didn't work, decrement and try again, this will eventually get us to 0
    {:error, _} -> fetch_data(id, retries_left - 1)

    # It works!  Return the payload
    {:ok, payload} -> payload
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### One-Line Functions

That's a short hand for writing one-line elixir functions. For example, you can write this function:

```ex
def add(x, y) do
  x + y
end
```

Like this:

```ex
def add(x, y), do: x + y
```

Notice the `do:` instead of `do`.

---

### Pattern Matching

The other thing that the code is using is **Pattern Matching** in function clauses. It allows developers to avoid tons of conditional statements to make decisions, instead let the compiler choose which function definition to call.

For example, see this:

```ex
def something(num, :inc), do: num + 1
def something(num, :dec), do: num - 1
```

Once defined, these two instances of the `something/2` function will handle arguments differently. So if you call `something(4, :inc)` it will "match" against the first definition and return `5`, if you pass `:dec` instead it will return `3`, but if the second argument is something else it will throw an `UndefinedFunctionClauseError`.